# Is it okay to post the same Project Euler solution, using the same language, but with a different implementation?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicates

I have come up with my very own Clojure implementation of the solution for Project Euler #2, but I see that [someone already solved this particular problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/300/project-euler-problem-2-in-clojure) using Clojure and put it up here for code review.

My implementation is quite different, and I would also like to get feedback on it. Would it be okay to post my code, even though it covers the same problem in the same language as a question that was asked before?

Comment: I would just like to thank you for stopping by Meta to check. Most people would have just posted it without bothering to ask.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is OK. "Duplicates" on Code Review are not the same concept as other sites.

If your code is not the same as other questions, then your question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I posted my code for review [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/project-euler-2-in-clojure).